# Jenkins not building dockerfile

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

jenkins doesn't like my docker build am I forgetting something
specifically I am getting this.

```
Started by user admin
Obtained Jenkinsfile from git http://gitlab.operasolutions.com/procurement-ai/procurement-ai-ui.git
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 17: Expected a step @ line 17, column 17.
                   def app = docker.build("procurementai-ui")
```

this is the error and this is the jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo build'
            }
        }
        stage('verify') {
            steps {
                sh 'ls -alF target'
            }
        }        
        stage('docker') {
            steps{
                sh 'cd /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/procurementai-ui'
                def app = docker.build("procurementai-ui")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Global var invocations need to be enclosed within `script` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

'def' is causing you troubles as Jenkins file would expect a step not a groovy command.

Here is how I did this:

```
stage('Build Docker Image') {
      steps{
        script {
          dockerImage = docker.build "${RegistryURL}/${ProjectName}:${ProjectVersion}"
        }
      }
    }
```

where ${RegistryURL}, ${ProjectName}, ${ProjectVersion} are variables I defined in the upper part of the file in the environment section.